# su-ing won't work

Tags: permissions, su

I want to run something with root privileges without making a user an admin/granting them sudo-ing power (effectively making them an admin). Therefore I wanted to test: `su adminuser echo "Hello World"` This only caused my to get the error message: `bash: echo: Permission denied`

Comment: Try `sudo sh -c 'echo "Hello world"'`

Comment: Commands may be passed to `su` via the `-c` option ex. `su adminuser -c 'echo "Hello $LOGNAME"'`

Answer (score 1):

The `su` command is usually used to run an *interactive* shell (by default, the shell listed in the target user's password database entry). If you want to use it to run a command non-interactively, you should pass the command string as an argument to the `-c` option, per `man su`:

> ```
>    -c, --command=command
>        Pass command to the shell with the -c option.
> ```

So that would be

```
su adminuser -c 'echo "Hello World"'
```

or

```
su -c 'echo "Hello World"' adminuser
```

---

*Note: the following is tested on Ubuntu 22.04 with the util-linux implementation of the `su` command. There may be slight differences in behavior if you are using a different implementation such as that from the `shadow` package - although I'm not aware of any currently-supported Ubuntu version that uses that by default.*

When you run `su adminuser echo "Hello World"`, the `echo` and `Hello World` are passed to the user's shell as *arguments*. Most shells will treat `echo` as the name of a file from which to read commands, with any remaining arguments as positional parameters. So for example:

```
$ sudo chsh -s /bin/sh testuser
$ su testuser echo "Hello World"
Password: 
sh: 0: cannot open echo: No such file
```

however bash (at least, bash 5.1.16) appears to try to resolve `echo` using the user's `PATH` and then fails because the result is a binary executable:

```
$ sudo chsh -s /bin/bash testuser
$ su testuser echo "Hello World"
Password: 
/usr/bin/echo: /usr/bin/echo: cannot execute binary file
```

The only circumstance in which I can reproduce `bash: echo: Permission denied` is if there is an unreadable local file named `echo`:

```
$ touch echo && chmod -r echo
$ su testuser echo "Hello World"
Password: 
bash: echo: Permission denied
```

Comment: I don't usually "enjoy" reading technical stuff as some enjoyment element seems to be always missing ... But, I actually enjoyed reading this answer.

Comment: @Raffa thanks - I realize I went down a bit of a rabbit hole to explain the OP's error message, so good to know it's not entirely TMI (at least, not for everyone)

Answer (score 0):

Consider something like setuid for that specific command.  I used it on the command pwrstat (associated with my UPS) which now can be run by anyone on the system. I used the chmod command to make it happen.  In my case the chmod command went like this:
sudo chmod 4755 /usr/sbin/pwrstat